# To integrate Mahout with already installed solr

Tags: solr, mahout

I have used solr to index and search pdf files.. it is working fine. Now I am said to use Mahout to my project and was told to integrate it with solr. I am new to this technology so please do help me from scratch. in a basic way....
Do i need to download and inmstall mahout first or will modifications in schema and solrconfig will make it? for integrating tika functionality it was just modification in the config file.

Answer (score -1):

Mahout is a separate project, so you have to download, install, and learn how to use it...will not be a one afternoon thing.

But, you should be aware of [this Lucene clasiffication module](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4345) (Solr is built on top of Lucene). It is not as complete as Mahout, but for not massive projects, with can work really well. The advantage is that it integrates with Lucene/Solr, so you have much less work to do. I have used successfully with Sorl4.6

Comment: Can you give me the steps in details what need to be followed ? I am new to this. Thanks in advance.